# Issues When Deploying Project on Shared Hosting / Godaddy /

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to deploy my Laravel app on Godaddy shared hosting but encounter issues. First of all, let me explain my directory structure.

I uploaded the public folder into "public_html" and on the same level as "public_html" I created a new folder, called it Laravel and placed all other files and folder in it. Then I changed the "index.php" file in "public_html" to the correct path. I also configured the database.conf and .ENV files and put the correct credentials for MySQL.

I encountered these issues:

When I open the website, I see an error page (Laravel error page :) ) which says

**"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from properties where deleted_at is null order by id desc limit 3)"**

I don't understand the reason for this as I have changed my db credentials.

I edited my homepage controller (the function that handles the "domain.com/" route ) so that it doesn't need a DB connection (just to experiment) and it threw this error -

**"View [welcome] not found."**

When I edit my "web.php" file (routing) so that it just returns a string, it works!

P.S. Everything works well on my local machine :/

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide grant to user used in your application from Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can set grant as,

```
     grant all privileges on YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.* to myuser@'localhost' identified by 'mypasswd';
```

Open your database configuration file use same username and password as above or whatever you want to set but should be same in both.

Comment: how do I set grant? Didn't get it.

Comment: You can do it from phpmyadmin if it's available, or by simply logging to database administration interface, and executing that query (make sure you replace the credentials with yours). You can also connect to mysql from the terminal if this is enabled in your hosting package.

Comment: didn't help.. I guess my problem is not the db connection. It can't even load view :/

Comment: Hi...@user7347995  Open your Mysql from phpmyadmin or workbench or from command line and set grant as above, keep user credentials same and restart your application / server after that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using laravel 5.4 version and it requires minimum version of php 5.6.4 so please try to change the php version in godaddy cpanel

Answer (score 0):

change db_host to `localhost` on .env file. it works for me